# An increasing sequence of compacts

Tags: real-analysis

In my textbook, it is asked to consider "an increasing sequence of compacts $K_n$ whose union is $R^d$\{0}..." without mentioning what they look like...
Taking for the moment d=1, I was thinking about the following $$K_n:=[-n;1/n]\cup[1/n;n]$$
But well, there are not really increasing, could you point me in the good direction ? :)

Thanks

Comment: yes $K_n:=[-n,-1/n]\cup[1/n,n]$ are increasing with respect to set inclusion. For $d\ge1$ you may take $K_n:=\{x:1/n \le |x| \le n\}$.

Comment: Perfect, it seems that I'm not even able to recognize that -1/n <-1/n+1 anymore... ~.~
Thanks !